# Is TLS finished message encryption at record protocol redundant?

Tags: tls

TLS finished message is encrypted under the record protocol's current cipher state. Being able to authenticate FINISHED message at record protocol proves that the genuineness of peer endpoint. Verifying handshake_hash proves that the handshake has not been tampered by MITM.

The verify_data in FINISHED is calculated using PRF and master secret. So the verification of verify_data should be a sufficient proof of both the authentication of peer and handshake message sanity.

Why additionally the record protocol does cipher operation on FINISHED message?
I think it could have been equivalent if FINISHED message were sent before change_cipher_spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do `Finished` after `change_cipher_spec`, and since `Finished` has to be the first message after setting the cipher spec, you get the added benefit of requiring a successful decryption of a message before any (potentially sensitive) user data is transmitted. This step serves as an extra "checksum".

From [Section 7.4.9 of RFC 5246:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (emphasis mine)

> The Finished message is the first one protected with the just
> negotiated algorithms, keys, and secrets.  **Recipients of Finished
> messages MUST verify that the contents are correct.**  Once a side
> has sent its Finished message and received and validated the
> Finished message from its peer, it may begin to send and receive
> application data over the connection.

### Edit:

You wonder if encrypting `Finished` is unnecessary given that `verify_data` provides sufficient authentication against tampering. I claim that an sending an unencrypted `Finished` message would be quite disastrous for TLS.

The end of a normal TLS handshake looks as follows:

$\text{client} \rightarrow \text{server}:$ `change_cipher_spec`

$\text{client} \rightarrow \text{server}:$ `Finished` $a_k$

$\text{server} \rightarrow \text{client}:$ `change_cipher_spec`

$\text{server} \rightarrow \text{client}:$ `Finished` $a_k$

$\text{client} \rightarrow \text{server}:$ `encrypted application data transmits...` $m_k$

Here, $a_k$ and $m_k$ are the authenticaton code for `Finished` and session data keyed by $k$. It's important to reiterate that before a `change_cipher_spec` message is received, the current cipher suite offers no encryption or authentication; it's still pending the negotiated parameters upon receipt of `change_cipher_spec`.

Now imagine Andy Adversary on the network observing this handshake. In the special case where the negotiated cipher suite only handles authentication and not encryption, Andy removes the `change_cipher_spec` messages, so that the client and server never update their cipher suites and thus **never enable authentication or encryption with the negotiated parameters. Welcome to catastrophe**. Now Andy sits in the middle, stripping off authentication fields from `Finished` messages and later sensitive session data. So now you have no authentication either.

Here's the modified, defeated handshake:

$\text{client} \rightarrow \text{adversary}:$ `change_cipher_spec`

$\text{client} \rightarrow \text{adversary}:$ `Finished` $a_k$

$\text{adversary} \rightarrow \text{client}:$ `Finished` $a$

$\text{server} \rightarrow \text{adversary}:$ `change_cipher_spec`

$\text{server} \rightarrow \text{adversary}:$ `Finished` $a_k$

$\text{adversary} \rightarrow \text{client}:$ `Finished` $a$

$\text{client} \rightarrow \text{adversary}:$ `unencrypted application data transmits...` $m_k$

$\text{adversary} \rightarrow \text{server}:$ `unencrypted application data transmits...` $m$

It's easy for Andy Adversary to strip off the MAC field since there's no encryption. So now he has not only access to unencrypted, unauthenticated messages, but he can also forge whatever messages he likes.

If encryption were part of the cipher suite as is normal, the attack is much harder, but the point is that by passing in `Finished` after `change_cipher_spec`, you eliminate even the possibility of the attack.

What I have described here comes directly from [Wagner and Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-ssl-revised.pdf), who knew of this attack by 1997. As a matter of fact, they note that Netscape's SSL 3 implementation was vulnerable to it. Read Section 4.3 of that paper for more details.

Their recommendation to prevent such attacks?

> The simplest fix is to require that a SSL implementation
> receive a change cipher spec message before
> accepting a finished message.

They recognize this as a basic flaw in the specification of SSL, which of course was corrected in TLS:

> Some readers might complain
> that this requirement ought to be obvious with a moment’s
> reflection, even if it is not explicitly stated in
> the SSL specification. We cannot fault such clarity of vision.

In general, this is not the only attack that can be prevented by the "checksum" argument, or what Bellare and Rogaway call [matching conversations](http://www.cse.msstate.edu/%7Eramkumar/eakd.pdf), where both client and server verify encryption and authentication before transmitting sensitive data. See [Section II-1](https://kryptera.se/assets/uploads/2013/02/Lessons-Learned-From-Previous-SSLTLS-Attacks.pdf) for another.

Conclusion: sending an encrypted `Finished` after `change_cipher_spec` is the simplest solution to protect the `change_cipher_spec` message.

Comment: I do not understand the 'checksum' argument. How does successful decryption of an extra message benefits? The RFC just states what the implementations have to do i.e. send Finished after ChangeCipherSepc and decrypt, verify it at recipient.  RFC does not tell what does encryption of Finished message achieve ...

Comment: The Finished message is the *first* message that the server and client transmit fully under the agreed-upon cipher spec, with all the server and client nonces and keys from the master secret. Before sensitive data is sent, you need a test message to verify that encryption, decryption, and authentication work. You verify there's no mismatch with them all at once with by encrypting and HMACing  Finished.

Comment: What does the verification of encryption by using a test message accomplish? How would it have weaken TLS security guarantees had FINISHED message would been un-encrypted?

Comment: Added further discussion above.

Comment: In DTLS1.3 draft, I see that the FINISHED message is placed in epoch=2 encrypted using handshake_traffic_secret, whereas the application data is placed in epoch=3 which is encrypted using traffic_secret_0. 

Why the checksum consideration mentioned above is not required here? Why the authors did not place FINISHED in epoch=2 itself?

Comment: You're asking a new question, so please post a new one so that the answer doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Short answer though: there's no more `ChangeCipherSpec` protocol. All messages after `ServerHello` are encrypted. Having `handshake_traffic_secret` be separate from `traffic_secret_0` more cleanly separates the handshake protocol from the record protocol, and `Finished` doesn't have to be the first encrypted message, screening out passive attacks earlier.